# Binding Sinch Android SDK to use in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, sinch, android-sinch-api

I am trying to bind the Android SDK Provided by Sinch for WEBRTC functionality. the sdk is in .aar and I have tried to bind it but i keep getting a bunch of errors. Please can someone with a good knowledge of Bindings in Xamarin put me through what I need to fix the errors.
Many Thanks

Attached error logs: `------ Build started: Project: SinchBindings, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Annotations.IExpose.cs(155,40,155,46): warning CS0114: 'IExposeInvoker.Equals(Object)' hides inherited member 'Object.Equals(Object)'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Annotations.IExpose.cs(182,38,182,49): warning CS0114: 'IExposeInvoker.GetHashCode()' hides inherited member 'Object.GetHashCode()'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Annotations.IExpose.cs(206,39,206,47): warning CS0114: 'IExposeInvoker.ToString()' hides inherited member 'Object.ToString()'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Annotations.IJsonAdapter.cs(155,40,155,46): warning CS0114: 'IJsonAdapterInvoker.Equals(Object)' hides inherited member 'Object.Equals(Object)'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Annotations.IJsonAdapter.cs(182,38,182,49): warning CS0114: 'IJsonAdapterInvoker.GetHashCode()' hides inherited member 'Object.GetHashCode()'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Annotations.IJsonAdapter.cs(206,39,206,47): warning CS0114: 'IJsonAdapterInvoker.ToString()' hides inherited member 'Object.ToString()'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Annotations.ISerializedName.cs(155,40,155,46): warning CS0114: 'ISerializedNameInvoker.Equals(Object)' hides inherited member 'Object.Equals(Object)'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Annotations.ISerializedName.cs(182,38,182,49): warning CS0114: 'ISerializedNameInvoker.GetHashCode()' hides inherited member 'Object.GetHashCode()'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Annotations.ISerializedName.cs(206,39,206,47): warning CS0114: 'ISerializedNameInvoker.ToString()' hides inherited member 'Object.ToString()'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Annotations.ISince.cs(127,40,127,46): warning CS0114: 'ISinceInvoker.Equals(Object)' hides inherited member 'Object.Equals(Object)'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Annotations.ISince.cs(154,38,154,49): warning CS0114: 'ISinceInvoker.GetHashCode()' hides inherited member 'Object.GetHashCode()'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Annotations.ISince.cs(178,39,178,47): warning CS0114: 'ISinceInvoker.ToString()' hides inherited member 'Object.ToString()'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Annotations.IUntil.cs(127,40,127,46): warning CS0114: 'IUntilInvoker.Equals(Object)' hides inherited member 'Object.Equals(Object)'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Annotations.IUntil.cs(154,38,154,49): warning CS0114: 'IUntilInvoker.GetHashCode()' hides inherited member 'Object.GetHashCode()'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Annotations.IUntil.cs(178,39,178,47): warning CS0114: 'IUntilInvoker.ToString()' hides inherited member 'Object.ToString()'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Internal.Bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.cs(70,57,70,61): warning CS0114: 'CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.Adapter.Read(JsonReader)' hides inherited member 'TypeAdapter.Read(JsonReader)'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Internal.Bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.cs(14,31,14,38): error CS0534: 'CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.Adapter' does not implement inherited abstract member 'TypeAdapter.Read(JsonReader)'
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Internal.Bind.DateTypeAdapter.cs(72,40,72,44): warning CS0114: 'DateTypeAdapter.Read(JsonReader)' hides inherited member 'TypeAdapter.Read(JsonReader)'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Internal.Bind.DateTypeAdapter.cs(9,30,9,45): error CS0534: 'DateTypeAdapter' does not implement inherited abstract member 'TypeAdapter.Write(JsonWriter, Object)'
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Internal.Bind.DateTypeAdapter.cs(9,30,9,45): error CS0534: 'DateTypeAdapter' does not implement inherited abstract member 'TypeAdapter.Read(JsonReader)'
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Internal.Bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory.cs(72,57,72,61): warning CS0114: 'MapTypeAdapterFactory.Adapter.Read(JsonReader)' hides inherited member 'TypeAdapter.Read(JsonReader)'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Internal.Bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory.cs(14,31,14,38): error CS0534: 'MapTypeAdapterFactory.Adapter' does not implement inherited abstract member 'TypeAdapter.Read(JsonReader)'
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Internal.Bind.SqlDateTypeAdapter.cs(72,39,72,43): warning CS0114: 'SqlDateTypeAdapter.Read(JsonReader)' hides inherited member 'TypeAdapter.Read(JsonReader)'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Internal.Bind.SqlDateTypeAdapter.cs(9,30,9,48): error CS0534: 'SqlDateTypeAdapter' does not implement inherited abstract member 'TypeAdapter.Write(JsonWriter, Object)'
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Internal.Bind.SqlDateTypeAdapter.cs(9,30,9,48): error CS0534: 'SqlDateTypeAdapter' does not implement inherited abstract member 'TypeAdapter.Read(JsonReader)'
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Internal.Bind.TimeTypeAdapter.cs(72,39,72,43): warning CS0114: 'TimeTypeAdapter.Read(JsonReader)' hides inherited member 'TypeAdapter.Read(JsonReader)'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Internal.Bind.TimeTypeAdapter.cs(9,30,9,45): error CS0534: 'TimeTypeAdapter' does not implement inherited abstract member 'TypeAdapter.Write(JsonWriter, Object)'
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Internal.Bind.TimeTypeAdapter.cs(9,30,9,45): error CS0534: 'TimeTypeAdapter' does not implement inherited abstract member 'TypeAdapter.Read(JsonReader)'
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Internal.Bind.TypeAdapters.cs(764,32,764,37): error CS0111: Type 'TypeAdapters.EnumTypeAdapter' already defines a member called 'Write' with the same parameter types
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Client.Calling.DefaultCallClient.cs(9,69,9,118): error CS0535: 'DefaultCallClient' does not implement interface member 'ICallClient.SetRespectNativeCalls(bool)'
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.JsonStreamParser.cs(9,75,9,102): error CS0738: 'JsonStreamParser' does not implement interface member 'IIterator.Next()'. 'JsonStreamParser.Next()' cannot implement 'IIterator.Next()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'Object'.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Internal.LinkedHashTreeMap.cs(370,102,370,116): error CS0115: 'LinkedHashTreeMap.InvokeEntrySet()': no suitable method found to override
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Internal.LinkedHashTreeMap.cs(32,31,32,39): warning CS0108: 'LinkedHashTreeMap.EntrySet' hides inherited member 'AbstractMap.EntrySet()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Internal.LinkedHashTreeMap.cs(81,31,81,37): warning CS0108: 'LinkedHashTreeMap.KeySet' hides inherited member 'AbstractMap.KeySet()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Internal.LinkedHashTreeMap.cs(10,30,10,47): error CS0534: 'LinkedHashTreeMap' does not implement inherited abstract member 'AbstractMap.EntrySet()'
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Internal.LinkedTreeMap.cs(392,102,392,116): error CS0115: 'LinkedTreeMap.InvokeEntrySet()': no suitable method found to override
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Internal.LinkedTreeMap.cs(14,24,14,32): warning CS0108: 'LinkedTreeMap.EntrySet' hides inherited member 'AbstractMap.EntrySet()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Internal.LinkedTreeMap.cs(103,31,103,37): warning CS0108: 'LinkedTreeMap.KeySet' hides inherited member 'AbstractMap.KeySet()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Internal.LinkedTreeMap.cs(10,30,10,43): error CS0534: 'LinkedTreeMap' does not implement inherited abstract member 'AbstractMap.EntrySet()'
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Org.Webrtc.Sinch.EglBase14.cs(119,69,119,83): error CS1715: 'EglBase14.EglBaseContext': type must be 'EglBase.Context' to match overridden member 'EglBase.EglBaseContext'
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Org.Webrtc.Sinch.EglBase14.cs(9,30,9,39): error CS0534: 'EglBase14' does not implement inherited abstract member 'EglBase.EglBaseContext.get'
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Client.ConfigRefresher.cs(9,87,9,121): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'UserAgentMethodInvocationScheduler' does not exist in the namespace 'Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Client' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Client.ConfigRefresher.cs(11,30,11,47): warning CS0109: The member 'ConfigRefresher.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Client.ConfigRefresher.cs(12,30,12,39): warning CS0109: The member 'ConfigRefresher.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Client.ConfigRefresher.cs(18,29,18,43): error CS0115: 'ConfigRefresher.ThresholdClass': no suitable method found to override
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Client.ConfigRefresher.cs(22,42,22,55): error CS0115: 'ConfigRefresher.ThresholdType': no suitable method found to override
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Client.ConfigRefresher.cs(79,34,79,39): error CS0115: 'ConfigRefresher.OnRun(IUserAgent)': no suitable method found to override
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Org.Webrtc.Sinch.ICameraVideoCapturer.cs(537,22,537,29): warning CS0108: 'ICameraVideoCapturerInvoker.Dispose()' hides inherited member 'Object.Dispose()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Gson.Stream.JsonToken.cs(94,57,94,61): warning CS0108: 'JsonToken.Name' hides inherited member 'Enum.Name()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Org.Webrtc.Sinch.IVideoCapturer.cs(407,8,407,15): warning CS0108: 'IVideoCapturer.Dispose()' hides inherited member 'IDisposable.Dispose()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Org.Webrtc.Sinch.IVideoCapturer.cs(500,22,500,29): warning CS0108: 'IVideoCapturerInvoker.Dispose()' hides inherited member 'Object.Dispose()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Org.Webrtc.Sinch.VideoRendererGui.cs(338,29,338,36): warning CS0108: 'VideoRendererGui.Dispose()' hides inherited member 'Object.Dispose()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Client.HouseKeeper.cs(9,83,9,117): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'UserAgentMethodInvocationScheduler' does not exist in the namespace 'Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Client' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Client.HouseKeeper.cs(11,30,11,47): warning CS0109: The member 'HouseKeeper.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Client.HouseKeeper.cs(12,30,12,39): warning CS0109: The member 'HouseKeeper.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Client.HouseKeeper.cs(18,29,18,43): error CS0115: 'HouseKeeper.ThresholdClass': no suitable method found to override
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Client.HouseKeeper.cs(22,42,22,55): error CS0115: 'HouseKeeper.ThresholdType': no suitable method found to override
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Client.HouseKeeper.cs(79,34,79,39): error CS0115: 'HouseKeeper.OnRun(IUserAgent)': no suitable method found to override
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Natives.IDispatchable.cs(13,8,13,15): warning CS0108: 'IDispatchable.Dispose()' hides inherited member 'IDisposable.Dispose()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Natives.IDispatchable.cs(85,22,85,29): warning CS0108: 'IDispatchableInvoker.Dispose()' hides inherited member 'Object.Dispose()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Client.Scheduler.cs(141,30,141,37): warning CS0108: 'Scheduler.Dispose()' hides inherited member 'Object.Dispose()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Client.Video.DefaultVideoController.cs(248,30,248,37): warning CS0108: 'DefaultVideoController.Dispose()' hides inherited member 'Object.Dispose()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Client.Video.IVideoControllerInternal.cs(18,8,18,15): warning CS0108: 'IVideoControllerInternal.Dispose()' hides inherited member 'IDisposable.Dispose()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Client.Video.IVideoControllerInternal.cs(107,22,107,29): warning CS0108: 'IVideoControllerInternalInvoker.Dispose()' hides inherited member 'Object.Dispose()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Client.Video.NullVideoController.cs(244,30,244,37): warning CS0108: 'NullVideoController.Dispose()' hides inherited member 'Object.Dispose()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Natives.Jni.DefaultUserAgent.cs(288,30,288,37): warning CS0108: 'DefaultUserAgent.Dispose()' hides inherited member 'Object.Dispose()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Org.Webrtc.Sinch.VideoCapturerAndroid.cs(444,30,444,37): warning CS0108: 'VideoCapturerAndroid.Dispose()' hides inherited member 'Object.Dispose()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Client.Video.VideoFrameSink.cs(75,30,75,37): warning CS0108: 'VideoFrameSink.Dispose()' hides inherited member 'Object.Dispose()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Org.Webrtc.Sinch.VideoRenderer.cs(451,30,451,37): warning CS0108: 'VideoRenderer.Dispose()' hides inherited member 'Object.Dispose()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Natives.Jni.IUserAgent.cs(46,8,46,15): warning CS0108: 'IUserAgent.Dispose()' hides inherited member 'IDisposable.Dispose()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Natives.Jni.NativeDispatchable.cs(47,30,47,37): warning CS0108: 'NativeDispatchable.Dispose()' hides inherited member 'Object.Dispose()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Natives.Jni.IUserAgent.cs(364,22,364,29): warning CS0108: 'IUserAgentInvoker.Dispose()' hides inherited member 'Object.Dispose()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Natives.Jni.Messaging.cs(47,30,47,37): warning CS0108: 'Messaging.Dispose()' hides inherited member 'Object.Dispose()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Natives.Jni.NativePubPublisher.cs(62,30,62,37): warning CS0108: 'NativePubPublisher.Dispose()' hides inherited member 'Object.Dispose()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Natives.Jni.NativePubSubscriber.cs(164,30,164,37): warning CS0108: 'NativePubSubscriber.Dispose()' hides inherited member 'Object.Dispose()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Natives.Jni.Session.cs(386,30,386,37): warning CS0108: 'Session.Dispose()' hides inherited member 'Object.Dispose()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Natives.Jni.NativeServiceProviderImpl.cs(62,30,62,37): warning CS0108: 'NativeServiceProviderImpl.Dispose()' hides inherited member 'Object.Dispose()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
1>C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SinchBindings\SinchBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Service.Serviceprovider.DefaultServiceProvider.cs(285,30,285,37): warning CS0108: 'DefaultServiceProvider.Dispose()' hides inherited member 'Object.Dispose()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========`

Comment: are we supposed to know what "a bunch of errors" means?  It would be much more helpful if you actually posted the text of the messages you're getting.

Comment: My apologies i will add the error log

Comment: Please see my binding guide for help on some of these items: https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb